# how to add search by date cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have the following code that displays a list of details from my Database.
It is paginated as well.

I want to add a search function that someone can search the provided data using " Date From - Date To "

Currenty source :

```
$tapplicant= $this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Tapplicant.*',
        'Toutcome.*'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'toutcome',
            'alias' => 'Toutcome',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.AppID = Toutcome.AppID' )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Tapplicant.AppDate >=' => date('y-m-d')
    ),
    'order' => array('Tapplicant.AppDate' => 'DESC'),
    'limit' => 15
);

$this->set('tapplicant', $this->paginate());
```

I display the data as followed :

```
<?php foreach ($tapplicant as $tapplicant) : ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?=$tapplicant['Tapplicant']['AppID']; ?></td> 
            <td><?=$tapplicant['Tapplicant']['AppAffID']; ?></td> 
            <td><?=$tapplicant['Tapplicant']['FirstName']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['Tapplicant']['LastName']; ?></td>           
            <td><?=$tapplicant['Tapplicant']['AppDate']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['Tapplicant']['AppDomain']; ?></td>
            <td>£<?=$tapplicant['Toutcome']['LenderCommission']; ?></td>
            <td><?=$tapplicant['Toutcome']['LenderName']; ?></td>

        </tr>
```

After doing some research and trying things like :

$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('AppID'=>5, 'DATE(AppDate)'=>'CURDATE()')));

I cant get it to work.
If someone could please assist on help with the controller and view side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN`:

```
$conditions = array(
  'Tapplicant.AppDate BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
    $start,
    $end,
  )
);
```

Read more about complex find conditions in CakePHP 2 here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: Where and how would i collect the value's "?" you put in. I understand the text box would have an ID , but how would i carry the value accross. Lets say the id for textbox 1 is "Tbox" , would it look like this. Tapplicant.AppDate BETWEEN $tbox1 AND $tbox2' => array( @jeremyharris

Comment: Keep the question marks, Cake will insert the array values into the appropriate spots. To get those values, it depends. It seems you will be using a form, so `$this->request->data` should have the user-submitted values.